# Is there a similar function as 'babel.transform().code' in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, web-component

I need to setup `webpack` to load web components. The trouble is that I also want to use `typescript`. So far the only solution I found is [web-components-loader](https://github.com/rnicholus/web-components-loader). It looks like it can transpile code from es6 using `babel`. Is there a similar possibility for `typescript`?

```
webComponentsLoader: {
    transformJs: rawCode => {
        return babel.transform(rawCode, {
            presets: ['es2015']
        }).code;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `transpile` method provided by the compiler:

```
import * as ts from "typescript";

let compiledSource = ts.transpile("let x: string  = 'string'", {
    target: ts.ScriptTarget.ES2015
});
```

See [the documentation on how to use the compiler API](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Using-the-Compiler-API.md).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately I couldn't use it. The loader seems to be incompatible with webpack2. Eventually I used `let app = new App();` and the usual `ts-loader` to trigger the execution of the web component. It worked.